# Data frame in R group by duplicated values in column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am struggling to perform a summarise/count operation in a dataframe in R.

I believe that this is caused by the fact that there are values in column A, which are mapped to at least two entries in column B.

A sample dput below:

```
structure(list(exercise_id = c(10026L, 10027L, 10028L, 10029L, 
10030L, 10031L, 10032L, 10033L, 10034L, 10035L, 10036L, 10037L, 
10038L, 10039L, 10040L, 10041L, 10042L, 10043L, 10044L, 10045L, 
10046L, 10047L, 10048L, 10049L, 10050L, 10051L, 10052L, 10053L, 
10054L, 10060L, 10061L, 10062L, 10063L, 10064L, 10065L, 10066L, 
10067L, 10068L, 10069L, 10070L, 10071L, 10072L, 10073L, 10074L, 
10075L, 10076L, 10077L, 10078L, 10079L, 10080L, 10087L, 10088L, 
10089L, 10090L, 10091L, 10092L, 10093L, 10094L, 10095L, 10096L, 
10097L, 10098L, 10099L, 10100L, 10101L, 10102L, 10103L, 10104L, 
10105L, 10105L, 10107L, 10108L, 10109L, 10110L, 10111L, 10112L, 
10114L, 10115L, 10116L, 10117L, 10118L, 10119L, 10120L, 10121L, 
10122L, 10123L, 10124L, 10125L, 10126L, 10127L, 10128L, 10129L, 
10130L, 10131L, 10132L, 10133L, 10134L, 10136L, 10137L, 10138L, 
10139L, 10140L, 10141L, 10142L, 10143L, 10144L, 10145L, 10146L, 
10147L, 10148L, 10149L, 10150L, 10151L, 10152L, 10153L, 10155L, 
10156L, 10157L, 10158L, 10159L, 10160L, 10161L, 10162L, 10163L, 
10164L, 10165L, 10166L, 10167L, 10168L, 10169L, 10170L, 10171L, 
10172L, 10173L, 10174L, 10175L, 10176L, 10177L, 10178L, 10179L, 
10180L, 10181L, 10182L, 10183L, 10184L, 10185L, 10187L, 10188L, 
10189L, 10190L, 10194L, 10195L, 10196L, 10197L, 10198L, 10199L, 
10200L, 10201L, 10202L, 10203L, 10204L, 10205L, 10206L, 10214L, 
10215L, 10216L, 10217L, 10218L, 10219L, 10220L, 10221L, 10221L, 
10223L, 10224L, 10225L, 10226L, 10227L, 10228L, 10229L, 10235L, 
10236L, 10237L, 10238L, 10239L, 10378L, 10379L, 10380L, 10381L, 
10382L, 10383L, 10384L, 10385L, 10386L, 10387L, 10388L, 10389L, 
10390L, 10391L, 10392L, 10393L, 10394L, 10395L, 10396L, 10397L, 
10398L, 10399L, 10400L, 10401L, 10402L, 10403L, 10404L, 10405L, 
10462L, 10463L, 10464L, 10465L, 10466L, 10467L, 10468L, 10469L, 
10470L, 10471L, 10472L, 10473L, 10474L, 10475L, 10476L, 10477L, 
10478L, 10479L, 10480L, 10481L, 10482L, 10483L, 10484L, 10485L, 
10486L, 10487L, 10488L, 10489L, 10490L, 10491L, 10492L, 10493L, 
10494L, 10495L, 10496L, 10497L, 10498L, 10499L), objective_1 = c("Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", 
"Liczby naturalne w dziesiątkowym układzie pozycyjnym.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", "Działania na liczbach naturalnych.", 
"Działania na liczbach naturalnych."), nested_level = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(27892L, 27893L, 
27894L, 27895L, 27896L, 27897L, 27898L, 27899L, 27900L, 27901L, 
27902L, 27903L, 28058L, 28059L, 28061L, 28063L, 28064L, 28065L, 
28066L, 28067L, 28068L, 28069L, 28071L, 28072L, 28246L, 28247L, 
28248L, 28249L, 28075L, 42795L, 42797L, 42799L, 42801L, 27904L, 
28076L, 28077L, 28078L, 28255L, 28257L, 28259L, 28260L, 28261L, 
28403L, 28405L, 28407L, 28335L, 28336L, 42805L, 42807L, 28392L, 
27917L, 27919L, 27921L, 27923L, 28082L, 28083L, 28085L, 28087L, 
28089L, 28091L, 28093L, 28095L, 28097L, 28098L, 28099L, 28272L, 
28401L, 28402L, 28404L, 42858L, 28356L, 42812L, 42813L, 42814L, 
42815L, 42791L, 27881L, 27882L, 27883L, 27884L, 27885L, 27886L, 
28040L, 27887L, 27888L, 28041L, 28042L, 28043L, 28044L, 28045L, 
28251L, 28252L, 28253L, 28254L, 28256L, 28258L, 28046L, 28354L, 
28355L, 28423L, 28424L, 28426L, 28427L, 28428L, 28429L, 28412L, 
28413L, 28414L, 28415L, 28101L, 28416L, 28102L, 28417L, 42808L, 
42809L, 28309L, 28310L, 28311L, 28312L, 28313L, 28314L, 28315L, 
28316L, 28317L, 28318L, 28319L, 28320L, 28321L, 28322L, 28323L, 
28324L, 28325L, 28326L, 28328L, 28330L, 28332L, 28294L, 28296L, 
28298L, 28300L, 28073L, 28074L, 28250L, 28345L, 28347L, 28349L, 
42831L, 42832L, 42834L, 42835L, 42836L, 27906L, 27907L, 27908L, 
28079L, 28080L, 28081L, 28262L, 28406L, 28425L, 42803L, 42804L, 
42806L, 28306L, 28307L, 28308L, 42810L, 42811L, 27925L, 27927L, 
28396L, 42859L, 28266L, 28397L, 28350L, 28351L, 28352L, 27928L, 
28100L, 42839L, 42841L, 42843L, 42846L, 42850L, 28124L, 28125L, 
28127L, 28129L, 28131L, 28132L, 28133L, 28134L, 27961L, 27962L, 
27963L, 27964L, 27966L, 27968L, 28135L, 28137L, 28139L, 28141L, 
28142L, 28143L, 28144L, 28145L, 28146L, 28147L, 28148L, 28111L, 
28113L, 28116L, 27988L, 27989L, 27990L, 27991L, 27992L, 27993L, 
27995L, 27996L, 27997L, 27998L, 27999L, 28002L, 28005L, 28007L, 
28170L, 28173L, 28176L, 28179L, 28181L, 28182L, 28183L, 28184L, 
28185L, 28187L, 28118L, 28190L, 28191L, 28192L, 28119L, 28120L, 
28022L, 28121L, 28122L, 28123L, 28016L, 28110L, 28019L, 28112L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried the dplyr package, especially the group_by and summarise function. But I get an error message like this:

```
Column `output$exercise_id` must be length 14 (the group size) or one, not 83329
```

This is what I have tried:

```
output <- output %>% group_by(objective_1) %>% count(output$exercise_id)
```

Comment: Don't think you need the `$` to reference `exercise_id` in `count()`. Give this a try: `output <- output %>% group_by(objective_1) %>% count(exercise_id)`

Comment: Hi tomasu, this works fine, but it does not really group the data, because the count will always be 1. I would like to see for example that for objective a the count is 12, for objective b the count is 8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways we could go about this. If we want to see how many unique values of `exercise_id` are within the groups defined by `objective_1` we could use `n_distinct()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

output %>% 
  group_by(objective_1) %>% 
  summarise(total = n_distinct(exercise_id))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   objective_1                                           total
#>   <chr>                                                 <int>
#> 1 Dzialania na liczbach naturalnych.                      220
#> 2 Liczby naturalne w dziesiatkowym ukladzie pozycyjnym.    30
```

Another option could be to use `count()` on just your `objective_1` variable:

```
output %>% 
  count(objective_1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   objective_1                                               n
#>   <chr>                                                 <int>
#> 1 Dzialania na liczbach naturalnych.                      220
#> 2 Liczby naturalne w dziesiatkowym ukladzie pozycyjnym.    30
```

Similarly, a base option is `table()`:

```
table(output$objective_1)
#> 
#>                    Dzialania na liczbach naturalnych. 
#>                                                   220 
#> Liczby naturalne w dziesiatkowym ukladzie pozycyjnym. 
#>                                                    30
```

Finally, I am quite fond of the `tabyl()` function in `library(janitor)`:

```
library(janitor)

output %>% 
  tabyl(objective_1)
#>                                            objective_1   n percent
#>                     Dzialania na liczbach naturalnych. 220    0.88
#>  Liczby naturalne w dziesiatkowym ukladzie pozycyjnym.  30    0.12
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi tomasu. This definitely helped. I really liked the janitor solution. As it seems that it is the most powerful one. Thank you !!